# Keydown event weird behaviour

Tags: vb.net, events, keydown

I'm trying to catch shortcut keys. I need an explanation on how `KeyDown Events` are managed. Let's take this as an example :

```
Private Sub SoldeOuvertFou_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+W")
        End If

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
          MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+F5")
        End If

  End Sub
```

Works perfectly. No matter which one I press first or how many times I press them both `MessageBox` will pop up. Now if I simply change the order inside the sub :

```
Private Sub SoldeOuvertFou_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
          MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+F5")
        End If

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+W")
        End If

  End Sub
```

With this approach, only `Ctrl+F5` will pop-up. No way to make `Ctrl+W` appear... any idea why ?

Comment: It works for me in both cases. Have you tried to debug it step by step to see the values on each line?

Comment: @SysDragon  weird....

Comment: Looks good to me.  I tested both and it works as expected.

Comment: As others have mentioned, the posted code works.  Try testing this on a different computer yourself.  MessageBoxes aren't great debugging tools, by the way.

Comment: @LarsTech I'll try it as soon as I can .. Don't know why it does not work on my setup.. anyways i'll go step by step and post results

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use :

```
If e.Control Then

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+F5")
    Else
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
           MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+W")
        End If

    End If

End If
```